# Touch Events, multiple game objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Please point me to an online tutorial or example, or demonstrate how-to -- showing how I can use Touch events to single-finger touch then swipe select multiple game objects in my view?  I've been looking online and at the Apple Dev Docs and cannot find anything that helpful (doesn't mean it isn't out there, just means I cannot find it).

Here's my scenario:

I have 3 enemy game objects moving towards my hero game object.  I want to touch one of the enemy game objects (activating it), then swipe to select the other 2, which will destroy all enemies (that part I can handle, implementing the correct touch events and having those events recognize my game objects, in this specific scenario, is where I'm stuck).

Specifics:
Using XCode 5 (Obj C), Sprite Kit, for iOS (not sure these details matter, but in-case).

Comment: Please remove "hold".  This is a valid programming question and one that can help many others.  The question does not "recommend or find a tool", "library" or "favorite off-site resource".  It does ask for help in pointing to an example and asks to provide one here or a link elsewhere, which isn't that same as the three reasons for putting this on hold.

Comment: Furthermore, I do describe the problem.  I'm curious if rmaddy, abizern, dbd and halr actually read my question.

Answer (score 2):

[Searching for Physics Bodies](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH6-SW32) gives a good example of how to use ray casting to test what physics bodies lie in a scene along a specified path.

You may be able to get away with calling `enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart:end:usingBlock:` for each `touchesMoved` event, but as an optimization, you can calculate what the closest object is to the current touch point, and only perform collision tests once your finger is close enough.

The thing to remember with this technique is that the ray points must be in scene coordinates. So you may have to use something like:

```
-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  CGPoint sceneTouchPoint = [[touches anyObject] locationInNode:self];
  [self.physicsWorld enumerateBodiesAlongRayStart:self.lastSceneTouchPoint end:sceneTouchPoint usingBlock:^(SKPhysicsBody *body, BOOL *stop) {
    NSLog(@"Node: %@", body.node);
  }];

  self.lastSceneTouchPoint = sceneTouchPoint;
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's pretty fancy. My current game doesn't require this, but I like that apple threw this in there. +1